# How will EM waves behave if they are made to pass through a region of intense magnetic/ electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

My question is exactly what the title says.

I think they should not be affected as photons are uncharged. But shouldn't the oscillating Electric and Magnetic fields be affected by the electric/ magnetic fields of the medium through which they propagate ?

Comment: If Electric and magnetic fields are uniform, they have no effect on em waves. If they are changing with time , interactions are same as inter photonic interactions.

Comment: It depends on the matter that's in there. There are maybe a dozen major effects that you would have to consider. Without matter... they are basically unaffected. Gamma-gamma collisions require an enormous energy density before they become measurable as a non-linearity of the physical vacuum.

Comment: Sharp edges have an remarkable inhomogeneous electric field and by this able to deflect EM radiation.